# How to return distinct sets in a PySpark RDD?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have an RDD, with a different set of values, and I want to return all the distinct sets from the original RDD. Is there any key term such as distinct?

```py
example = sc.parallelize([{1}, {2}, {3}, {1}])
example.collect()
```

This outputs:

```
[{1}, {2}, {3}, {1}]
```

I tried `example.distinct().collect()` and the answer I was expecting is an RDD with distinct sets:

```
[{1}, {2}, {3}]  # expected result
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to `frozenset` because these can be hashed. You can then call `distinct` as usual:

```
example.map(frozenset).distinct().map(set).collect()
# [{1}, {2}, {3}]
```

As pault suggested, you can also convert the sets to `tuple` before dropping duplicates.

Comment: It can also be mapped to a `tuple`.

Comment: @pault That's right. I suggested `frozensets` first because I assumed they wanted to do something with sets (rather than just collect the result after).